# In non-metals, does low specific heat capacity correlates with good thermal conductivity and vice versa?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, kinetic-theory, heat-conduction

As i understand, when heat transfers by conduction, there are two main mechanisms that can take place: either by the vibrations of the lattice (mostly non-metals) or with the movement of free electrons (mostly metals)

What does it mean, in a microscopic level, when our non-metal material has a low specific heat capacity? It means that most of the heat that's being transferred to it, will turn into kinetic translational energy of the molecules and NOT rotational kinetic energy, or vibrational kinetic energy (of the atoms within the molecules).
So most of the heat energy will increase the translational motion of the molecules and temperature will rise. If that same heat energy was used up both in translational and rotational kinetic energy of the molecules then the material would need more heat energy to raise its temperature by one degree and hence it would have a bigger specific heat capacity. That's because a material's temperature rises only due to the translational motion of its molecules not rotation or anything else.

Now when it come to the lattice of a non metal, does it vibrate more due to the translational kinetic energy of its molecules or do other types of energies play any role?
If the lattice of a non metal material depends more on the kinetic translational energy, than any other type of energy, then a low specific heat capacity would mean good conductivity, right?

To summarize my thought process:

Low specific heat capacity ---> most of the heat becomes translational kinetic energy of the molecules

High transnational kinetic energy of molecules ---> vibrates lattice more strongly

Strongly vibrating lattice spreads heat faster---> good conductivity

If anyone made it this far to my question, THANK you honestly‍♂️. I am not a native English speaker and i wanted to be as clear as possible, hence the big paragraph.